# SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Node is unhealthy

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli, solana-program-library

I'm trying to send a transaction with a memo program inside it.
The problem appears on solana cli and web3 too.

This is the command:
`solana transfer --from ./.cache/solana.json RECIVER_PUBLIC_KEY 0.00001 --allow-unfunded-recipient --url https://api.testnet.solana.com  --fee-payer ./.cache/solana.json  --with-memo hello`

and this the response:
`Error: RPC response error -32005: Node is unhealthy`

The same with typescript/js snippet:

```
async function sendRawTransaction(message:string):Promise<string>{
    const connection = await new Connection(CONNECTION_STRING);
    let tx = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.transfer({
          fromPubkey: WALLET.publicKey,
          toPubkey: RECIVER_ADDRESS,
          lamports: 0,
        }),
      );
    await tx.add(
        new TransactionInstruction({
          keys: [{ pubkey: WALLET.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true }],
          data: Buffer.from(message, "utf-8"),
          programId: MEMO_PROGRAM,
        })
    );
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
        sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [WALLET]).then(s=>{
            console.log(s)
            res(s)
        }).catch(e=>{
            console.log(e)
            rej(e)
        })
    })
}
```

and the response is:

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Node is unhealthy
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/manueltardivo/Sviluppo/Notarify/Refactor/ntf-blackbox/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6812:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/manueltardivo/Sviluppo/Notarify/Refactor/ntf-blackbox/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6769:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/Users/manueltardivo/Sviluppo/Notarify/Refactor/ntf-blackbox/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6759:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/Users/manueltardivo/Sviluppo/Notarify/Refactor/ntf-blackbox/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2219:21) {
  logs: undefined
}
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Node is unhealthy
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/manueltardivo/Sviluppo/Notarify/Refactor/ntf-blackbox/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6812:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/manueltardivo/Sviluppo/Notarify/Refactor/ntf-blackbox/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6769:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/Users/manueltardivo/Sviluppo/Notarify/Refactor/ntf-blackbox/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6759:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/Users/manueltardivo/Sviluppo/Notarify/Refactor/ntf-blackbox/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2219:21) {
  logs: undefined
}

Node.js v18.4.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've already tried to delete node_modules and re install them.
Could be a problem with the RPC provider?

Answer (score 0):

Copying my answer from https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/solana-error-creating-memo-program-node-is-unhealthy-solana-web3/

Under normal circumstances, "node is unhealthy" often means that the node has fallen behind from the rest of the network, so you either need to wait for it to catch up, or you need to use another RPC node.

However, I can tell you that testnet is currently down, so you'll need to use another network until it's back up, either devnet or a local `solana-test-validator`.